# Execute a command-line command from CruiseControl.NET

Tags: selenium, nunit, cruisecontrol.net

I have this block of code in the [CruiseControl.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CruiseControl) configuration:

```
<exec>
    <executable>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe</executable>
    <buildArgs>/C SETX SELENIUM_BROWSER googlechrome /M</buildArgs>
</exec>
```

It is followed by an [NUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUnit) execution command that will run some [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) tests on my website. The idea is that this command changes the testing browser (system environment variable) before the tests are run.

The problem is that the command does not seem to be working. The tests are still using the default browser, Firefox. It works if I manually change the environment variable.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I tried putting the command in a batch file and executing that, but it still didn't work:

```
<exec executable="C:\CCNet\setChrome.bat" />
```

The batch file contents:

```
SETX SELENIUM_BROWSER googlechrome /M
```

Comment: Generally, I keep the CC.NET config very simple and just kick off NANT or other build scripts that are much better at defining build actions.  CC is for orchestration and reporting results, but not that great at defining builds.

Comment: I'm not really doing anything exceptional. CC.NET supposedly has the functionality to run a simple command. I just don't understand why it's not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Formatting the command like this sets the environment variable correctly:

```
<exec>
    <executable>cmd</executable>
    <buildArgs>/C SETX SELENIUM_BROWSER googlechrome /M</buildArgs>
</exec>
```

Now I need to figure out why my NUnit tests aren't correctly picking it up.

UPDATE:

Should have used the `environment` element in the executable task to pass variables to the test. For example:

```
<exec>
    <executable>make</executable>
    <baseDirectory>D:\dev\MyProject</baseDirectory>
    <buildArgs>all</buildArgs>
    <buildTimeoutSeconds>10</buildTimeoutSeconds>
    <successExitCodes>0,1,3,5</successExitCodes>
    <environment>
        <variable>
            <name>MyVar1</name>
            <value>Var1Value</value>
        </variable>
        <variable name="MyVar2" value="Var2Value" />
    </environment>
</exec>
```

I actually implemented the browser setting in a little config text file as a workaround, but this element would have made it easier and I wouldn't have needed to run any command line commands.