# How to run a CruiseControl task as an administrator in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, cruisecontrol.net, keil

I'm currently using [CruiseControl.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CruiseControl) to automate my build. We have two different ways to build a solution in my build environment - one is through the [Keil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keil_%28company%29) uVision4 IDE, the other is through Visual Studio 2008.

I've successfully gotten the Visual Studio solution to build properly using CruiseControl.NET and have created a batch file which properly uses Keil's uVision command line interface to compile my uvproj Project ([compilation details here](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/uv4/uv4_commandline.htm)).

### Problem Description

1)  I can successfully execute the build script on my Windows 2008 server and build the project if I create a command prompt with administrator privileges (I'm doing this manually - start -> run -> cmd with ctrl-shift-enter to run as admin).

2) However, if I create a command prompt *without* administrator privileges, and attempt to execute the batch file, the batch file won't work unless I accept the prompt asking me to confirm admin rights are required to run the batch script.

How do I automatically execute a batch file as an administrator through CruiseControl?

Is this something that could be automated using the [RunAs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command?

---

### Technical details

1) The batch file being executed is pretty simple - it deletes the old output and re-makes the output, creating a build log file in the location below.

```
set BuildLogLocation=BuildLog\BuildLog.txt

echo on
cd ../..
cd PTM
rmdir /s /q output
mkdir output
mkdir BuildLog
C:\Keil\UV4\UV4.exe -r myProj.uvproj -o %BuildLogLocation%

echo ErrorLevel of build is %ERRORLEVEL%
echo build complete, see %BuildLogLocation%
```

2) Currently I'm looking to use the Exec functionality to run the Keil build script above:

```
<Exec>
    <Command>C:\myProject\Build\KeilBuild\BuildScript.bat<Command/>
    <buildTimeoutSeconds>600<buildTimeoutSeconds/>
    <!-- Details about error codes can be found here:
    http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/uv4/uv4_commandline.htm -->
    <successExitCodes>0,1</successExitCodes>
<Exec/>
```

Related questions:

- *[How can I use a build server with Keil uVision4 (MDK-ARM), script a build, use a makefile?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12404)* ([Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/about))
- *[Execute a command-line command from CruiseControl.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233389)* ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/about))

Answer (score 1):

Can you run CCService, the CruiseControl.NET Windows Service, as a user who has administrative permissions?  I'd try that first.

If that doesn't work, I would use runas to run your script.  You'll have to embed the administrative user's password in the script calling runas.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but, Did you get an offical way to do it Via Cruise Control?

Normally I create this and call it to call other processes "As Admin".

Make a ".VBS" script with This in the contents:

> Dim strBatchPath
>
> strBatchPath = "`PATH-TO-FILE.EXE`"
>
> Set runBatch = CreateObject("shell.application")
>
> runBatch.shellexecute strBatchPath,,,"runas",1

That could be an option to people that can't find an official way

Answer (score 0):

You could try psExec from sysinternals. If you don't need to run as a nt-authority account you should be able to use this in the same way as runas.
It allows you to pass in the username/password as a switch (if memory serves)

Answer (score 0):

I have Discovered that when using PSEXEC and using the `-h` switch, it then "runs as admin" on destination

e.g.

> psexec -h \ServerToRunOn /accepteula -u DOMAIN\USER -p PASSWORD "PATH-TO-FILE"

I am Using CC.Net to call a batch file with the above in. This will run that file as Admin